# Writing header and footer to the output file for a database to file job

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a db to file job.

The item writer is as below:

```
<beans:bean id="myReportFooterCallback" class="com.myPackage.util.MyReportFooterCallback">
    <beans:property name="delegate" ref="myReportFileItemWriter" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myReportFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="resource" value="file:c:\TestData\output_report.dat" /> 

    <beans:property name="lineAggregator">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator">
            <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                 <beans:property name="names" value="BUSINESS_DATE, FIELD_ONE, FIELD_TWO, FIELD_THREE, FIELD_FOUR, FIELD_FIVE, FIELD_SIX " /> 
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>

            <beans:property name="format" value="%-12s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-5s%-5s%-10s" /> 
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>

    <beans:property name="footerCallback" ref="myReportFooterCallback" />

</beans:bean>
```

And the step is as below:

```
<step id="ReportFileGenerator">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="jobRepository-transactionManager">
            <chunk reader="ReportFileItemReader" writer="myReportFooterCallback"  commit-interval="1000"/>
        </tasklet>
</step>
```

The class MyReportFooterCallback is as below:

```
public class MyReportFooterCallback implements ItemWriter<MyReportBean>, FlatFileFooterCallback {

private ItemWriter<MyReportBean> delegate;

private double totalDebitAmount = 0.0;
private double totalCreditAmount = 0.0;
private int totalDebit = 0;
private int totalCredit = 0;

public void write(final List<? extends MyReportBean> items) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("in write method!");

    int chunkDebitCount = 0;
    int chunkCreditCount = 0;
    double chunkDebitTot = 0.0;
    double chunkCreditTot = 0.0;

    for (MyReportBeanitem : items) {
        if (item.getIndicator().equalsIgnoreCase("Debit")) {
            // its a debit
            chunkDebitCount = chunkDebitCount + 1;
            chunkDebitTot = chunkDebitTot + Double.parseDouble(item.getTRANS_AMT());

        } else {
            // its a credit
            chunkCreditCount = chunkCreditCount + 1;
            chunkCreditTot = chunkCreditTot + Double.parseDouble(item.getTRANS_AMT());

        }
    }

    this.delegate.write(items);

    this.totalDebit = this.totalDebit + chunkDebitCount;
    this.totalDebitAmount = this.totalDebitAmount + chunkDebitTot;
    this.totalCredit = this.totalCredit + chunkCreditCount;
    this.totalCreditAmount = this.totalCreditAmount + chunkCreditTot;
}


public void writeFooter(final Writer writer) throws IOException {

    writer.write("\n");
    writer.write("\n");
    writer.write("Total Debits Processed: " + this.totalDebit);
    writer.write("\n");
    writer.write("Total Debit Amount: " + this.totalDebitAmount);
    writer.write("\n");
    writer.write("\n");
    writer.write("Total Credits Processed: " + this.totalCredit);
    writer.write("\n");
    writer.write("Total Credit Amount: " + this.totalCreditAmount);
}


public void setDelegate(final ItemWriter<MyReportBean> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

}
```

However, above code is not working as expected:

1) The file output_report.dat gets generated with the seven columns.However, the footer doesn't show the total values. All four values are 0 (the count and the total).

What am I missing ?

2) Also, is it possible to add the column names to the top of each column ?

3) Any way to add page numbers to the output report ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick try with a similar example works for me without a problem* (even without step scope)

1) did you try a JUnit test to be sure it works ? next step would be debugging/logging

2) sure, there exists a HeaderCallback too

3) not out of the box, but it should not be too hard to implement it, use the totalCount, divide by pagesize, print after items if result is a whole-number

(*) your example does not seem complete, i had to register the myReportFileItemWriter as a Stream

Comment: That was what I was missing :D  Thanks... It works.. There are number of occassions where some item data is to be used in header (e.g. some date). Pity we cannot do that through header call back :(